# Rabbit-mq multiple-queues, same consumer, share load

Tags: rabbitmq, exchange-server, load-balancing, message-queue, rabbitmq-exchange

!(https://image.ibb.co/jXgPRy/stackoverflow.jpg)

I'm trying to achieve this using rabbitmq queues and exchanges. Direct queues
with routing keys just fanout to queues with same routing key. What i am trying to acheieve is more of load balancing and queues scaling.

Please do help me out.

Updated image
https://image.ibb.co/cCgSUJ/stackoverflow.jpg